# スイッチの状態を取得する公式サイトのコードが動かない

Tags: onsen-ui

公式サイトの「[スイッチの状態取得](https://ja.onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-switch.html)」がコピペでも動作しない様ですが、仕様変更されたのでしょうか？
**html**

```
<ons-switch id="switch-1"></ons-switch>
```

**JS**

```
var switch = document.getElementById('switch-1');
ons.notification.alert('Value is ' + switch.checked);
```

Comment: 「動作しない」というのは具体的にはどういう挙動を示すのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

公式サイトの「スイッチの状態取得」のページ（https://ja.onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-switch.html）に実例として掲載されているHTML(?)には、switch-1というIDを持つエレメントがありません（というか、IDが指定されたエレメントが皆無です）。(2020/03/16 10:55時点)

なので、switch=document.getElementById('switch-1');　では何も得られず、
switch.chekedを表示しようとしたところで、エラーになっているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 翻訳中と書かれている個所が散見されますので、まだ作成中のページなのではないかと推測されます。
作成中なので、HTMLなどの内容も”まぁ、こんな感じかなぁ”ぐらいで、動作するレベルに達していないのではないでしょうか。